# Spans causing new lines

Tags: html, css

I have successfully created some CSS that allows me to mimic the look of the Powershell ISE color scheme, so I can show code on my web site somewhat elegantly. Now I am refining it to minimize the hand coding required, and I am stumped by the behavior of my spans.

Given HTML of

```
<code class="px_code">
<span class="px_code_reference">
<span class="px_cc_ise">Some code</span>
<span class="px_cc_ise_variable">Some more code</span>
<span class="px_cc_ise">Even more code</span>
</span>
<span class="px_code_new">
<span class="px_cc_ise">Some code</span>
<span class="px_cc_ise_variable">Some more code</span>
<span class="px_cc_ise">Even more code</span>
</span>
</code>
```

And CSS of

```
.px_code {
  line-height: 1em!important;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
.px_code_reference {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.px_code_new {
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
/* PowerShell ISE color coding */
.px_cc_ise {color: #000000;}
.px_cc_ise_attribute {color: #00BFFF;}
.px_cc_ise_command {color: #0000FF;}
.px_cc_ise_commandArgument {color: #8A2BE2;}
.px_cc_ise_commandParameter {color: #000080;}
.px_cc_ise_comment {color: #006400;}
.px_cc_ise_groupEnd {color: #000000;}
.px_cc_ise_groupStart {color: #000000;}
.px_cc_ise_keyword {color: #00008B;}
.px_cc_ise_lineContinuation {color: #000000;}
.px_cc_ise_loopLabel {color: #00008B;}
.px_cc_ise_member {color: #000000;}
.px_cc_ise_newLine {color: #000000;}
.px_cc_ise_number {color: #800080;}
.px_cc_ise_operator {color: #A9A9A9;}
.px_cc_ise_position {color: #000000;}
.px_cc_ise_statementSeparator {color: #000000;}
.px_cc_ise_string {color: #8B0000;}
.px_cc_ise_type {color: #008080;}
.px_cc_ise_unknown {color: #000000;}
.px_cc_ise_variable {color: #FF4500;}
```

I would expect there to be no space between the first three lines and the second three. But in fact there are 2! As if


Is creating those new lines, but my understanding is that a Span never creates a new line. Is this something I am missing in my CSS? Or my understanding of Span?

If I change my HTML to

```
<code class="px_code">
<span class="px_code_reference">
<span class="px_cc_ise">Some code</span>
<span class="px_cc_ise_variable">Some more code</span>
<span class="px_cc_ise">Even more code</span></span>
<span class="px_code_new"><span class="px_cc_ise">Some code</span>
<span class="px_cc_ise_variable">Some more code</span>
<span class="px_cc_ise">Even more code</span>
</span>
</code>
```

where the reference span is closed at the end of a line of code, and the new span is opened at the beginning of the next one, rather than those two items being on their own lines. But still, my understanding is Span never does a new line.
I am hoping for a CSS solution, since forcing it to work makes everything MUCH harder to read. But the alternative is to have the styling for the transparency and bold part of each and every line of code, and that's the kind of extra work I was trying to avoid if possible.

My live sketchbook page is [here](https://www.pragmaticpraxis.com/sketchbook-2/), which may be the best way to look into this, as lord knows how many interactions there are with Wordpress, my theme, and various edits.

Comment: Could you switch the code over to a snippet editor? I peeked really quick and didn't see anything egregious. Perhaps an image otherwise showing what the issue is?

Comment: @Jhecht I added a link to my actual sketchbook page, since there is a lot of other CSS and Wordpress/theme stuff that could also being sneaking in to trip me up. Thanks!

Comment: It's your Wordpress integration, as the code by itself [*does not produce the error*](https://jsfiddle.net/L3ztpjwh/). Please provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have to agree with @ObsidianAge -- when just using the raw html/css provided I don't have that error. when looking at your sketchbook page I see that there are `<br>` elements between each `<span>`, which is what is causing the new lines.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go to some other resources then. Obviously the problem doesn't exist in a minimal example, and doers exist in the real world example, which StackOverflow can't deal with. Likely the forum for the theme will be more helpful. thanks!